# Why some tcp_[rw]?mem$ voodoo show all equal values?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

Looking at TCP optimization guides across the Internet, a common theme is setting the tcp_mem, tcp_rmem, or tcp_wmem three-integer vector to have equal values in the sysctl.conf file.

Borrowing from the TCP man page, the function of the values are described as such:

**low**

- TCP doesn't regulate its memory allocation when the number of pages
  it has allocated globally is below this number.

**pressure**

- When the amount of memory allocated by TCP exceeds this number of
  pages, TCP moderates its memory consumption. This memory pressure
  state is exited once the number of pages allocated falls below the
  low mark.

**high**

- The maximum number of pages, globally, that TCP will allocate. This
  value overrides any other limits imposed by the kernel.

Maybe I'm crazy, but based on these descriptions, setting equal values might cause a horrible internal conflict.

Can someone smarter than me regarding TCP memory in the Linux kernel speak on the effects of setting theses values to be equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, lots of people have no idea what they are talking about and don't think for themselves so they just cargo-cult settings from elsewhere without understanding what those settings do or the true meaning of the tunables.

You are obviously not one of those people. Have an upvote!

Setting all three values of the `tcp_.mem` tunables to the same thing would ruin TCP's ability to auto-tune buffer sizes and memory usage (the `net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf=1` tunable) which is a nice advantage of the Linux TCP implementation.

Assuming the values were all high, this would be an inefficient use of TCP memory.

If enough sockets were created that the ceilings defined by `net.ipv4.tcp_mem` are hit (note these are measured in *pages*, not bytes) then TCP would be more inefficient as it starts collapsing buffers together to reduce memory usage, which would lead to higher `%sys` CPU usage than is really required.

If there was enough memory pressure, the kernel would start dropping packets, first from the out-of-order queue, then the main receive queue.

The correct value for the `tcp_rmem` tunables is:

- low: 4kb or 8k (one or two pages if not x86)
- default: the [BDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product) of your most commonly-served connection
- high: some value greater than the default, which allows for bulk transfers and for the delay an application has in reading from the socket buffer

For 1Gbps, 4Mb~6Mb is usually sufficient. For 10Gbps, you might want to go up as high as 16Mb. I haven't seen a system where higher than that has been useful, but maybe such a system exists.

You can usually leave the `tcp_wmem` tunables as they are.

The longer the system is up and serving network connections, the better TCP's auto-tuning will get at predicting the ideal default buffer size based on previous connections' BDP and RTT.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up confusion.  The idea that you could set tcp mem values all to be equal just didn't sit right given what each value represents and how the system acts upon those values.

Comment: And it should be mentioned that tcp_mem has a totally different meaning as it is pages per system and not bytes per connection. Unless you have a very extreme concurrency the system defaults should be fine for that.